# How do I use the PAM capabilities module to grant capabilities to a particular user and executable?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, pam, linux-capabilities

I'm attempting to make a program which uses raw sockets run correctly as non-root with Linux capabilities. The program is as follows:

```
#include <netinet/ip.h>

int main()
{
  int sd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_TCP);
  if(sd < 0)
  {
    perror("socket() error");
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

If I compile it and run it as non-root, I get an error, as expected:

```
[user@localhost ~]$ make socket
cc     socket.c   -o socket
[user@localhost ~]$ ./socket 
socket() error: Operation not permitted
```

If I add the `cap_net_raw` capability, as an effective and permitted capability, it works.

```
[user@localhost ~]$ sudo setcap cap_net_raw+ep socket
[sudo] password for user: 
[user@localhost ~]$ ./socket 
[user@localhost ~]$
```

Now, I want to use `pam_cap.so` to make it so that only a particular user can run this program with `cap_net_raw`, instead of everyone. My `/etc/security/capability.conf` is:

```
cap_net_raw user
```

My `/etc/pam.d/login` is (note that I also tried `/etc/pam.d/sshd` but that did not seem to work either):

```
#%PAM-1.0
auth [user_unknown=ignore success=ok ignore=ignore default=bad] pam_securetty.so
auth       substack     system-auth
auth       include      postlogin
#Added this line to use pam_cap
auth       required     pam_cap.so
account    required     pam_nologin.so
account    include      system-auth
password   include      system-auth
# pam_selinux.so close should be the first session rule
session    required     pam_selinux.so close
session    required     pam_loginuid.so
session    optional     pam_console.so
# pam_selinux.so open should only be followed by sessions to be executed in the user context
session    required     pam_selinux.so open
session    required     pam_namespace.so
session    optional     pam_keyinit.so force revoke
session    include      system-auth
session    include      postlogin
-session   optional     pam_ck_connector.so
```

I had an ssh session, I logged out and back in after that and executed the following commands:

```
[user@localhost ~]$ sudo setcap cap_net_raw+p socket
[sudo] password for user: 
[user@localhost ~]$ getcap socket
socket = cap_net_raw+p
[user@localhost ~]$ ./socket 
socket() error: Operation not permitted
[user@localhost ~]$
```

My question is:  Why was I not able to execute the 'socket' program with `cap_net_raw`? I thought that when I logged in, my user would obtain it as a permitted capability, and it would allow 'user' to run 'socket' with the `cap_net_raw`.

This is what I'm running on:

```
[user@localhost ~]$ uname -a
Linux localhost.localdomain 3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Jun 30 12:09:22 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[user@localhost ~]$ cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS Linux release 7.0.1406 (Core)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that I had the wrong capabilities on the file.  In order for the process to be able to obtain effective capabilities from the pam_cap module, the file needs to be configured with the "inherited" capability as well.  So, setting caps on the file should be:

```
sudo setcap cap_net_raw+ip socket
```

However, I still could only get the program to work successfully from a normal tty login, and not an ssh login.

Comment: This should be `ie` and not `ip`. If you use `p` here you are forcing the bit to be raised independent of what Inheritable values the invoking process has. For posterity (this question/answer is quite old), I've supplied a more complete answer.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this question when trying to use Google to jump to the [`pam_cap.so`](https://sites.google.com/site/fullycapable/pam_cap-so) documentation.

The way to use `setcap` to set this binary up for use with `pam_cap.so` is:

```
sudo setcap cap_net_raw=ie socket
```

That is, the `i` instructs the binary to promote the process Inheritable capability flag into a process Permitted `p` capability, and the *legacy* `e` instructs the kernel to raise its value in the process' Effective flag when the program is invoked.

You can skip the `e` part if you want to use `libcap`s `cap_set_proc()` function to raise the Effective flag from inside the program. Something like:

```
    cap_t c = cap_get_proc();
    cap_fill(c, CAP_EFFECTIVE, CAP_PERMITTED);
    cap_set_proc(c);
    cap_free(c);
```

FWIW I've [recently written an article on the various ways you can inherit capabilities](https://sites.google.com/site/fullycapable/inheriting-privilege) in the modern kernel.